# unable get output on the same line with space in between the two output in c++

Tags: c++

This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()

{

int s,count1;
long long N,R,max1;
cin>>s;

for (int i=0; i<s; i++)
{
    cin>> N>>R;
}
cout<< N << R <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

for input

```
  1
  5 6
```

output

```
  56
```

but I want the output as

```
  5 6
```

I am good in c know how to do the same in c,now started learning c++  please help

Comment: change to `cout<< N << "\t" << R <<endl;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the output stream is being read as is, it is printing the characters contained in `N` and `R` consecutively. You need to specify to print a space/tab. Your output line should be:

`cout<< N << " " << R <<endl;`

That will put a space between the two characters. If you want a tab (which might be nice if you're doing multiple lines of output and want everything to be lined up nicely), replace `" "` with `"\t"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a space to be outputted, then output one!

`cout << N << R << endl` says output `N`, output `R` and then output a newline and flush the buffer. If you want a space, you need to add it to the output:

```
cout<< N << ' ' << R <<endl;
```